# Check for support of Javascript delete functionality

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, ecmascript-5, browser-feature-detection

In Javascript you can `delete` an object property:

```
var o = { x: 1, y: 2 };

var wasDeleted = delete o.x;
```

Now `o.x` should be `undefined` and `wasDeleted` is `true`.

However you can only delete native objects, and unfortunately the browsers seem to have different ideas on this:

```
window.x = 1;

delete window.x;
```

Now in Chrome and IE9-10 `x` will be `undefined`, but in IE6-8 this throws an exception:

> "Object doesn't support this action"

Great. Note that this isn't that `delete` is unsupported...

```
// Oops, no var, so this is now a global, should've 'use strict'
o = { x: 1, y: 2 };

// Works
delete o.x;

// Works
delete window.o.y;

// Fails, but only in IE6-8 :-(
delete window.o
```

I realise that I can add a `try {...} catch` block, but...

Is there any way to check whether a browser supports `delete` against a particular object *before* it is called?

I.e. can I tell whether a property is considered *host* or *native* by the browser?

Comment: Host objects (such as *window*) are not required to behave like native objects (like instances of Object). When dealing with host objects (such as DOM objects), you should use methods specified in that object's interface because deleting a property of a host object may have significant consequences not accounted for in the language (ECMAScript) specification (e.g. deleting the *checked* property of an input element).

Comment: @RobG I get that, the odd bit is that (in IE6-8 only) `window.o.x` is considered to be a native property while `window.o` is considered to be host one. What I want to do is detect (without `try-catch`) which one the browser thinks it is.

Comment: What have you got against try/catch? It's supported in every browser since IE5 and this is the right way to detect something like this. My suggestion is to test `delete` on a different host object that you don't mind polluting and use the result to tell if it will work on `window` without throwing.

Comment: @PHPGuru this question is from 11 years ago, IE support of any kind is no longer a requirement. However, as a general rule, `try-catch` _should_ be used as little as possible, and feature detection should be the first choice for this. In IE `delete` worked on most other objects (including ones you'd think IE treated as 'host'), just not `window` - there was no way to test for this. My question was is there a way around that?

Comment: I don't see why people shouldn't support old browsers anymore. There are still a lot of them out there especially on old devices. I know someone who recently told me he still uses Windows 98SE/IE6 for gaming reasons. I can't blame anyone for not wanting to support IE anymore though. Try/catch to me is a lot easier than always walking on egg shells. I personally make use of it as much as possible because it means writing less code and there isn't any significant overhead these days.

Comment: @PHPGuru money. We don't support them because if developing a feature to work in all Chromium variants, Safari and Firefox takes X days then also supporting IE will make that 3-5 times as many days (if it's even possible) and only reach a tiny number of additional users. I've been developing JS since 1997 and supporting IE was horrendous, especially as before IE7 there were no dev tools - slapping `try-catch` on everything isn't a solution - the DOM models are different, CSS is different, most features are missing, it's a whole different app.

Comment: There's something to be said though for taking the time to support older browsers even if not IE6 at least IE11 if you can afford to pay for it and obviously only on pages that need it. And I still don't see the problem with try/catch if you know how to use it. I don't think there's anything wrong with writing code like `try {foo = one.two.three.four.five} catch(e) {/*do something else*/}` instead of `foo = one?.two?.three?.four?.five` which won't work on old browsers. Babel is better than nothing but it's not as good as writing your own backward compatible code.

Comment: @PHPGuru bit too much for this discussion and worth it's own question, but `try-catch` is _slow_. Do it a lot, and nest it a lot, or use it in loops and it can jank your JS app pretty quickly (especially on ancient or mobile devices). If you need IE11 at this point a whole simplified copy of your app is a more cost effective solution.

Comment: There's something to be said about writing code that is concise and try/catch is good for that. But I agree that you should optimize loops good man and when in doubt benchmark your code

Comment: @PHPGuru again for a full question, but typically `try-catch` is not concise or clean. At the very least you have code + handler or code + alt-code, and you only want to handle any specific exception _once_: log the whole stack, instead of error at each call or worse error at lowest call and silent at the top. Problems where an exception from external code is the only way (as here) are one of the only use cases, but it's _still better practice to test first instead of catch with fallback_ (hence this question). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14980639/905

Comment: Speaking only of JavaScript: I think try/catch being slowish isn't really a good reason not to use it, unless you're optimizing loops and such, then just find a way to move the try/catch call out of the loop just as you would any other time consuming code that doesn't need to be executed O(n) times. But it's not that I disagree with any of this.

Comment: @PHPGuru that's great, until you have components that libraries that call libraries, but if you want IE support you need a `try-catch` at the **top**? Or rely on documentation to tell people not to call it in a loop? `try-catch` is a compromise, it's _always_ a compromise, sometimes it's worth it, but it's very rarely best practice. It's a compromise here too.

Comment: The thing about JavaScript is that there are many examples where try/catch is your only way to test something. I blame JavaScript itself for being a horrible language. But that's what you have to deal with on the web. Besides the performance of try/catch isn't that bad really. But it's definitely worth avoiding in loops if possible where performance is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delete` is a basic javascript language feature which also is supported by IE6-8. It's just that these legacy browsers deal differently on deleting *imutable* or *native* / *host* object properties. I'm afraid a `try-catch` statement is your only option to cover this.

Comment: I kinda figured something like that - it's odd that you can extend a _host_ object (by accident event, just forget to `var`) but then that global property is sort-of _host_ instead of _native_. There should at least be some way to detect that.

Comment: @keith—that is a very special case. It is a language feature that assigning to an undefined variable creates a property of the global object. It is a feature of the DOM that there is a *window* object that is more or less an alias for the global object.