# How to get multiple rows from access database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

I am trying to store each row of a access database, based on column `Veh_ID`. The found data may or may not be based on multiple rows. The code I am currently using can copy single row but if there are multiple results I can only get the first result. Can anyone please help me on this? I am noob when it comes to database. I tried to search Google but no one seems to be needing what I need. Here's the code I'm using:

```
string cmd1 = "SELECT * FROM Veh_checkup WHERE Veh_ID = " + veh_idd + "";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd1, con);            
OleDbDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
read.Read();
veh_id=null;

int i=0;

foreach (var a in read)
{
    try
    {
        veh_id = veh_id + " " + read[i].ToString();
    }
    catch { }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things I would point out, some specific to your question, some not:

- **[USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html)**
- Use `OleDbDataReader.Read()` to move to the next record.
- Use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings in a loop, using `string = string + "something"` will create a new string on the heap with each iteration
- Use `using` blocks on Disposable objects
- `catch { }` is [not good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14974163/1048425). You will never know an error occurred. At the very least you should log the error somewhere so you know you need to fix something.
- `OleDbDataReader[i]` will get the data from column `i` for the current record being read, not the data from row `i`
- Don't use `SELECT *` in production code, especially if you are only using 1 column. It is unnecessary data retrieval from the database and also unnecessary network traffic.
- **[USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html)**

Okay, I know I included using parameterised queries twice, but that is how strongly I feel about it!

With the above changes made, your full code will become something like:

```
static string GetStringData(string vehID)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    string cmd1 = "SELECT Column1 FROM Veh_checkup WHERE Veh_ID = @VehID";
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("YourConnectionString"))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd1, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VehID", vehID);

        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                builder.Append(" " + reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the datareader in a wrong way. Instead of calling it once like you do, you have to call the datareader in a while loop like this:

```
while(theDataReader.Read())
{
    // do your stuff in a loop now
}
```

So using this approach in your code would look something like this:

```
string cmd1 = "SELECT * FROM Veh_checkup WHERE Veh_ID = " + veh_idd + "";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd1, con);            
OleDbDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
veh_id=null;

con.Open();
while(read.Read()) //your reader
{
    try
    {
        veh_id = veh_id + " " + read[i].ToString();
    }
    catch { }

}
```

Comment: still no luck. it only returns single row. could you please explain what "theDataReader" variable is for here? I used "read" instead of it (in while loop)

Comment: well your statement suggests that you are only requesting one datarow. That is the datarow which id is matching the Veh_idd.

Comment: actually i have multiple results that correspond to same "veh_id" so i need to get them all. can you please suggest how to request multiple rows?

Comment: That is the code to fetch multiple rows. Check this example for a full example: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_data_reader.html

Comment: if this or another answer was helpful you should consider to mark it as an answer or post your own answer instead