# How to keep running a program if an exception occurs?

Tags: c#, exception

I have an application that connect with two server. If it cannot connect with a server, an exception is thrown. I want the program to continue executing and instead try to connect to the other server.  How can I do that?

Comment: `try{//...}catch(Exception ex){//...}`

Comment: Why all the down votes?  Granted this question is a very basic question about how `C#` works, but does it not have value for absolute beginners?

Comment: @beto13 - Recommend reading Rob Milles free C# Yellow Book for a good introduction to C#, with topics including Exception Handling: http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/

Comment: @PhilipPittle - If you hover over the downvote icon it states that "this question does not show research effort" (for the record I didn't downvote this question but I have downvoted numerous similar questions)

Comment: @Sayse - I get the research argument.  Just not sure how an absolute beginner would show research effort in a basic language construct.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/121162/1224069.  Maybe the downote hovertext has changed over the years.

Comment: @PhilipPittle - I don't want to spam this post any more but when I type into google "C# How to keep running a program if an exception occurs?" (the op's question title with c# prefixed); the top results are a stack overflow question, a tutorial on exception handling, and then 6 msdn links all about handling exceptions

Comment: @PhilipPittle Yes, questions like that exist, but that was 6 years ago. The rules of what's allowable on SO and the standards of a good question have changed dramatically since then ], not to mention that this question has been asked many times before.

Comment: Dang, wrong link. A better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973642/how-using-try-catch-for-exception-handling-is-best-practice

Answer (score 1):

Use a try catch block.

```
var serversToTry = new []{"Server1", "Server2"};

foreach (var server in serversToTry)
{

    try{
       //connect to server
       return;  //if you made it this far, connection succedded.
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //log e if you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the go to function `try-catch`:

```
try
{
   //do something
}
catch(SpecificException ex)
{

}
catch(LessspecificException ex)
{
}
catch(EvenLessSpecificException ex)
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  //general exception
}
finally
{
  //execute always!
}
```

Note, that you can use multiple `catch` statements to catch different exceptions. Use the most specific exceptions first and generalize from there on.
the `finally` statement is optional, but if you implement it, it will get called everytime, no matter if an exception occured or not.