# Exception throw within try-catch block

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to catch [`System.Windows.Automation.ElementNotAvailableException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.elementnotavailableexception(v=vs.110).aspx) but when the exception happens, visual studio still throw it. Why and how do I fix this?
I looked up for [`System.Windows.Automation.ElementNotAvailableException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.elementnotavailableexception(v=vs.110).aspx) on Exception Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> on VS 2015 commnunity) and that type isn't checked.

The try-catch block look like this:

```
try
{
    appElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, condition);
}
catch(ElementNotAvailableException)
{
    appElement = null;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you press F5, it should go the catch block and continue normal program execution.

Comment: why don't you do this instead `catch(ElementNotAvailableException ex){ MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }`

Comment: Are you sure the Exception is of type ElementNotAvailableException

Comment: Is the exception of the type ElementNotAvailableException?

Comment: I think OP is confused about what try/catch does.  Although, you do not have the ElementNotAvailableException checked in Exception settings, your code is still "catching" the exception.  This is supposed to happen.

Comment: The type is really `ElementNotAvailableException`. Maybe I'm confused, I want to program doesn't stop when the exception of this happen, I thought the application would move on on handled exceptions

Comment: If you want the program to continue execution, you NEED to catch the exception just as you are doing now.  Otherwise, the program will encounter an unhandled exception and terminate.  Where is the program blowing up?  As others mentioned, are you sure an ElementNotAvailable exception is being thrown.  If so, then the statement in your catch section should be getting hit.  Is this true?

Comment: This was my question, I did catch the exception but the programm still found an unhandled exception and terminated, at line of code inside the try catch block. I found out it was a VS settings issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution. I went to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> unchecked "break when cross appDomain or managed/native boundaries (Managed only) option.

And it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Review this post on exception handling.

[How using try catch for exception handling is best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973642/how-using-try-catch-for-exception-handling-is-best-practice)

Also, consider adding a generic exception catch block after your current catch block. This will catch other errors besides the specific exception error of the current catch block.

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // exception handling and/or display
}
```