# C# should I use try catch within a try catch to handle response? is it a bad idea?

Tags: c#, .net, model, try-catch

My code handles some rest APIs (GET methods). This GET method, returns a response like this:

```
{"error":0,"Logs":[{"LoggerIdx":"91","OfficeID":"MIA1A0955","Agent":"581A78AD"}]}
```

and if the query doesn't find anything, returns:

```
{"error":0,"Logs":[{"No values found"}]}
```

The code I'm using call this API to retrieve the values and show a report is:

```
private string uri = "http://localhost";

    public async Task<List<T>> GetWSObjects<T>(string uriActionString)
    {
        return new List<T> { await this.GetWSObject<T>(uriActionString) };
    }

public async Task<T> GetWSObject<T>(string uriActionString)
    {
        T returnValue =
            default(T);
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);                    
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uriActionString);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(((HttpResponseMessage)response).Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
        }
    }
```

returnValue tries to fill my model with the values in the response. However, when the response only contains "No values found" it breaks(obviously). My question is, should I place a try-catch within this try-catch to handle this behavior? The problem is that the whole exception is being shown to the user, not only "Not values found". Suggestions? My model is:

```
    public class BuildingReportModel
{
    public string message1 { get; set; }
    public Log[] Logs { get; set; }        
}

public class Log
{
    public string ProdLoggerIdx { get; set; }
    public string OfficeID { get; set; }     
    public string Agent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you are simply rethrowing the error. you can even get rid of the outer try catch all together

Comment: @Steve I thought about it, but what about catching other real errors, like bad input, sql ?

Comment: You should take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14974163/6936343).

Comment: Try catch inside a try catch makes my throw up in my mouth just a little.  Guy at my work put them in the finally block, so it could be worse....

Answer (score 3):

The best way of handling that would be to check the response before parsing it:

```
var responseString = await ((HttpResponseMessage)response).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
if(response.ToLower().Contains("no values found")) {
    //do something here like returning an empty model
}
else
{
    returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
}
```

Comment: .Result is a really good way to shoot yourself in the foot....potential deadlock if current SynchronizationContext is not null

Comment: this way makes sense, however, this "response" doens't have ToLower, neither Contains methods

Comment: sorry didn't see it, had to refresh to see that last comment

Answer (score 0):

In your `catch` block, log or otherwise capture the exception, but don't `throw` if the return value of this method is being displayed (which from what you posted seems like it is).  Then write a friendly message to your model (I'm assuming that is what the `string message1` property is for? If not you could possibly add a property to it for just such purposes).  That way your user will see something that **you** wrote which is much more likely to be understood than the details of the exception.

As far as doing another try catch - you could, *but it isn't necessary*.  Whatever exceptions are thrown by `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` will ultimately be of type `Exception` and will be caught by your `catch`.  If you want to catch a specific exception type, put another catch statement **before** your Exception catch block, and treat it in the same fashion.

Articles and opinions about how to re-throw (which is what your current code does) are all over the place - do some research and find the best pattern for your situation.

Also, the answer provided by @Yaser is a good idea as well - if you can prevent the exception in the first place, the rest is moot.

So here is an example of your posted code which I modified and commented in a little bit, which may help clarify (there is room for improvement but that is outside the scope of your question):

```
  public async Task<T> GetWSObject<T>(string uriActionString)
    {
        var returnValue = default(T);
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uriActionString);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                // this does not need a try catch, 
                // because whatever exception is thrown here 
                // will still be caught
                returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
                    response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // log or otherwise capture the exception details
            // if you don't need to log/capture the e variable
            returnValue.message1 = "A user-friendly description of the problem";
        }
        //catch // could also do it this way
        //{
        //    // if you don't need to log/capture the exception,
        //    // then don't bother with the overload
        //    returnValue.message1 = "A user-friendly description of the problem";
        //}

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: the tricky part here is that I'm passing a LIST so I can't access directly to returnValue message1, and if I do something in the catch, how can I identify each problem, in my case, that "No values found"?

Comment: @Rolando F - I can certainly provide a suggestion, but you asked "My question is, should I place a try-catch within this try-catch to handle this behavior? The problem is that the whole exception is being shown to the user, not only "Not values found". Suggestions?"  I believe I have answered your question and provided some suggestions.  If you still need help I can take a closer look and provide more feedback, but I wanted to point this out.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if it is the best way to solve it like this, but it is working:

```
catch (Exception e)
        {                
            if (e.Message.ToString().Contains("No Logs"))
            {
                Exception e2 = (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(e.GetType(), "No Logs Found ...", e);
                throw e2;                    
            }
            throw (e);
        }
```

I'm just verifying if the exception contains "No logs" and if is true, create a new exception and throw it. Seems to work, but is there any cons on doing it like this? any thoughts?