# How to delete rows of two different table having same id mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda, http-post

I am doing a project and in that I two table agent and user. The user table contains a foreign key. so here I need to delete an item in the table and at the same time it must effect to the user table and must delete the row in the user table that having the same id of the other that was deleted.

Comment: can you show AgentMaster model?

Comment: first you have to remove all the users what are related to agerntmaster then you can delete the agentmaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error occurs when your table is dependent on another table in your case its `one to many` relationship 
so add this in your `dbcontext`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AgentMaster>()
    .HasOptional(c => c.Users)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Comment: you just have to add this in dbcontext and you can check this   [DbContext.OnModelCreating Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: @user355 in code you showed db.AgentMasters how are you initializing the db?

Comment: and A is your dbcontext?

Comment: you dont have to rename just add the above code in dbcontext (A)

Comment: if you already have OnModelCreating  then just add the code inside already created OnModelCreating

Comment: @user355 can you add db context in question

Comment: @user355 remove    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException(); from dbcontext

Comment: @user355 when ever you override any predefined function it sets exception by default so you have to remove it if you want to change its default implementation. you can accept my answer if it helped :)

Comment: @user355 you dont have to throw exception in OnModelCreating  and if you want to handle exception just use [Try Catch Block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973642/how-using-try-catch-for-exception-handling-is-best-practice) in action

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server for Database, then just open your SQL Management Studio and open relationship windows for columns on which you have defined Foreign Keys relation. There is an option <kbd>Insert And Update Specification</kbd>, Expand it and for <kbd>Delete Rule</kbd>, select <kbd>Cascade</kbd> option.

[image]

For your scenario, after making these changes, if you delete `agent id` from `agent` table then it will automatically delete data referenced by this `agent id` in your `user` table.

Answer (score 0):

you don't any activity on asp.net , but you can enable Cascade option on relation between two table in dbms.

Comment: You are asked in this post clearly marked : [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573410/how-to-delete-rows-of-two-different-table-having-same-id-mvc/43573495#answer-43573945)

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly delete the record of one table that is being referenced by another table with foreign key.

You will have to explicitly delete the related rows of the users table or you can use ON DELETE CASCADE to automatically delete the rows of the users table.