# How to stop breaking on certain types of exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I would like to stop breaking on `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException`, as you can see in my Exception Settings, I have it unchecked, but it still breaks.

How can I filter them out?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How using try catch for exception handling is best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973642/how-using-try-catch-for-exception-handling-is-best-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck this:
[image]
You get this exception, because it's unhandled.

Comment: Cool thanks. If I want to get it back again, how to do so? If I don't get the exception box anymore

Comment: @ibiza here is manual: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/07/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/