# Net Core Catch statements with other Business Logic in Parsing Files

Tags: c#, parsing, asp.net-core, error-handling, try-catch

I am writing a simple program to parse a text file and place into Generic List.

Sample Text:

```
1,Joe,CA,58,2
2,Matt,TX,63,5
```

Sometimes, there may be an error, with missing data in the file

```
1,Joe,CA,58   // missing one number
2,Matt,TX,63,5
```

I wrote a Catch Statement to handle error. 
At the end, the Customer needs a file with which lines that caused error.

My Software Principle Question is, should catch statements be utilized to handle other business logic, in case of error, or should it only be used for raising exceptions?
In this catch statement, I am then creating an error folder, and file with data which caused issue. Is this appropriate?
See Catch statement below.

-

```
public class CustomerData
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerState { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int QuantityBought { get; set; }
}

public List<CustomerData> GetCustomer(string filename)
{
    List<CustomerData> customerdata = new List<CustomerData>();
    string CustomerBase = filename;

    String fileToLoad = String.Format(CustomerBase);
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fileToLoad))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(',');
            // Skip the column names row
            if (parts[0] == "id") continue;

            try
            {
                CustomerData dbp = new CustomerData
                { 
                    CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]),
                    CustomerName = parts[1],
                    CustomerState = parts[2],
                    ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(parts[3]),
                    QuantityBought = Convert.ToInt32(parts[4]),
                };
                customerdata.Add(dbp);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Parse Error!");

                string ErrorFolderPath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Parsefile\ErrorFile";
                string ErrorFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(ErrorFolderPath, Path.GetFileName(filename));


                bool FolderExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(ErrorFolderPath);
                if (!FolderExists)
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ErrorFolderPath);

                bool ErrorFileExists = System.IO.File.Exists(ErrorFile);
                if (!ErrorFileExists)
                    System.IO.File.Create(ErrorFile);

                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ErrorFile))
                {
                    tw.WriteLine(line);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return customerdata;
}
```

Comment: The catch should be used to do whatever you need to do to handle the error.  In your case, your handling is susceptible to exceptions too and hence should be wrapped in try-catch.  I would suggest reviewing the answer to [how using try catch for exception handling is best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973642/how-using-try-catch-for-exception-handling-is-best-practice).  Also, the user of your parsing method would want to know that the parse had failed, so throw an exception out or allow the actual exception to bubble up, whichever is more useful to the user.

Comment: To avoid parsing slowdown with multiple errors and having to deal with file writing too often, I would recommend aggregating the errors instead and writing them once before returning the results.

Comment: As Ian said, you might also want to separate the parser error handling from the error _reporting_ since users may not want to end up with error files but would rather be able to access the errorneous lines in a different way.

Comment: if someone wants to write a basic or outline template of how code should look like, would help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, that's wrong. In your `catch{}` block you should logically be logging and re-throwing the exception (OR) based on your system requirement may retry the same operation. But, having those other processing like creating folder or files aren't suggested since if those operation fails (for some reason) then those won't be catched and your application will break un-gracefully.

Comment: Thank you, where should put the logic then for creating Error folders, etc? can you reorganize my code a little bit, with basic header or templates? Thanks-

Comment: @CarSpeed87 you should be having a pre-defined location (folder) where you would want to place your log files. Creation of log files shouldn't be part of catch block. In catch you would just log the error stack trace in the same log file

Comment: ok, I can move out the folder creation in beginning, however what If I want multiple log files, each named from file its parsing?

Comment: I think you are correct, remove the create directory out of the catch block,  should I just have the error handler call a single ErrorMethod with rest of the catch code inside it? so it calls just one method statement?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, I ended utilizing any Logger, Nlog is this particular case.
Let me know if this is proper coding standards. Or feel free to comment.

```
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] parts = line.Split(',');
                // Skip the column names row
                if (parts[0] == "id") continue;

                try
                {
                    CustomerData dbp = new CustomerData
                    { 
                        CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]),
                        CustomerName = parts[1],
                        CustomerState = parts[2],
                        ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(parts[3]),
                        QuantityBought = Convert.ToInt32(parts[4]),
                    };
                    customerdata.Add(dbp);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Error(ex, "Got exception."); 
                    logger.Info(line);
                }
            }
```