# Is it possible to use a method throwing an exception in an if statement condition? c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, exception, try-catch, throw

so I am trying to error handle my code and so far this is what I have:

```
date = GetDate(); 
if(date.throws_exception())
{
// would it be possible to make a condition for where you can say if date throws exception?
}

string GetDate()
{
    try
    {
        .
        . 
        .
        return date;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

What I am wondering is it would be possible for the if condition, can you say:

```
if(date throws exception)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do those things in the catch-block?

Comment: Yes, in a indirect way. Instead of `GetDate` return a string, return a Tuple `(bool exceptionThrown, string value)`, where the bool indicate if an exception has been thrown. You can do `if(date.exceptionThrown)`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the built in `DateTime.TryParse` method?

Comment: Are you trying to develop an error handling strategy? If so, you probably want to bubble up your errors and not create too many `result` objects to then check for errors. A link that may help your error handling strategy, if that's your intent with this question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973642/how-using-try-catch-for-exception-handling-is-best-practice

Answer (score 2):

You could put the method call in a try catch block, or rewrite your method to return a result object, or a tuple indicating success and holding the value.

Example returning tuple indicating success:

```
(bool Success, string Value) GetDate()
{
    try
    {
        .
        .
        .
        return (true, date);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return (false, null);
    }
}
```

Use like:

```
var result = GetDate(); 
if (result.Success)
{
    // do something with result.Value
}
```

Comment: Similarly, and if you don't like Tuples, use the 'Try' prefix naming convention, like `bool TryGetDate(out string Value)`.  Usage: `var success = TryGetDate(out string value);  if (success) { Console.WriteLine(value); }`

Comment: Following from Sean's advice, if a `'Try'` method already exists, such as `int.TryParse()`, it will almost always be better to use that method than to catch the exceptions and handle them yourself.

Comment: Personally, as I'm married, I attributed my old implementation of a `TryGetDate` method with `[Obsolete]`.  But I hope everyone else's implementations don't throw exceptions.  ;)